# Textarea tag not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textarea

I'm not able to enter  text after one single on textarea  field, if once i double click on the textarea filed then I'm able to enter  text and then single click I'm able to enter text in that  filed, is it mandatory that double click first time in textarea filed in  IE Browser,  if someone help me what is the issue it will be more  helpful for me and  thanks  in advance

Comment: *single  ===>  single click

Comment: Please edit your post